# Tridion 2013 SP1 Publishing

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, sdl-tridion

I am working on Tridion 2013 sp1 and publishing was working fine. But the network team did some changes on server where we have deployer setup, after that the publishing stopped working. Seems the logs are also not generating now. I did verify all the config file, all looks good to me. Please help, not able to figure out the issue. I'm trying to publish single page only, it doesn't seem a package size issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you Try to restart the transport and publisher services and try to Publish again.

Comment: could be firewall blocked, deployer endpoint not accessible from cms/publisher servers. check the cd_core logs of the transport service. also validate using telnet command to check deployer endpoint is accessible from cms server.

Answer (score 2):

Please check following:

1. network firewall
2. certificates
3. restart transport service
4. connectivity between CM and broker DB
5. connectivity between CM and Deployer server [if CM and Deployer servers are different]
6. Check incoming folder in deployer server. is it receiving any package. in current situation it should not be. but it's worth to check.
7. revisit all connection strings in config files

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment that "the network team did some changes on server where we have deployer setup" the most likely issues will be:

- Deployer not running (is it a service or an HTTP upload web application?
- Firewall blocking the Deployer port from other servers (if the Deployer server is a Windows Server most likely it is the Windows Firewall blocking it)

The error indicates that the transport service is unable to connect to the deployer, so telnet first from the Deployer server itself to the port, if that works try to telnet from the CMS server to the deployer server and port.